# Action items appear to the left of the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Running my app with custom `ActionBar` and with two action bar items, displayed differently on different devices. On one device, the items appear to the left of the action bar logo and on the other device the action items appear to the right.

Action bar view:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_advanced"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Action bar items:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- logout action -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo1"
    android:title="logout"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    compat:showAsAction="never"
    />

<!-- go to position-->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search_position"
    android:icon="@drawable/position_a"
    android:title="search_position"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    compat:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Activity callback:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Dynamically action bar initialization in `OnCreate` of my main activity that extends `Activity`:

```
        ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
        View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

- The only device on which the action items are to the left of the action bar logo is Galaxy 2 (old device with build in overflow menu button). On this device WhatsApp and YouTube apps also appeared like this (in opposed to newer devices with proper appearance), but on the other hand, other apps like Tinder and Gmail keeps same appearance on all devices.

Any idea why?

Comment: I guess it's because one device has the developer option "Force RTL layout direction" on. Check it in Settings app of the device.

Comment: Could you direct me to that option? I could not find it.

Comment: Open Settings app (device's one) -> scroll all the way down -> Developer options -> look carefully for something like "Force RTL layout direction".

Comment: No such option on my device (Galaxy 2)

Comment: Oh so my guess was wrong I guess, probably because of compatibility issue of ActionBar with old versions of Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of action bar? This is now the recommended way of adding action bars.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code and extends  ActionBarActivity instead Activity from support AppCompat ActionBar library

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="always"  />
      <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" 
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```